# Select data that has already been pulled from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sorry if the title is not clear, I really don't know what kind of title this would be. I will start by what I'm working on. I'm trying to help my company with storing data and pull them away from a really big excel file. I have a web page that shows data from MYSQL using PHP and placed into a table. I have it set to where you can update and delete user information. What I need to do now is that they will need to print selected few people from the list that they see. So I thought with the data that was already pulled I can have a form with checkboxes for them to select the users they want to send to another page for them to print it. I was thinking of away for me to select the

```
echo $rows['id'];
```

that was posted for that user. I can't seem to find out how to get the id already posted. I see how i did the update user by

```
<td align="center"><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"><font color="Blue">Update</font></a></td>
```

But that just selects that one user. here is the code im working with.

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name=""; // Database name
$tbl_name=""; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY lname";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


?>










<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mysite.css">


</head>

<body>

<div id="title">
<center>
<img src="Logo.jpg" />
</center>

<p class="intitle"><font size="3"><a href="form.html" title="Add New Client"><font     color="blue">New Client</font></a></p>
</div>



<br />
<br />




<center>



<table width="600" border="1" cellspacing="0" >
<th>Print</th>
<th>                    <strong>PRG</strong>        </th>
<th class="name">       <strong>NAME</strong>       </th>
<th class="sex">        <strong>SEX</strong>        </th>
<th>                    <strong>PHASE</strong>      </th>
<th>                    <strong>DOCKET</strong>     </th>
<th class="date">       <strong>INTAKE</strong>     </th>
<th class="address">    <strong>ADDRESS</strong>    </th>
<th class="phone">      <strong>PHONE</strong>      </th>
<th class="phone">      <strong>ALT PHONE</strong>  </th>
<th class="date">       <strong>LAST OV</strong>    </th>
<th class="date">       <strong>LAST HV</strong>    </th>
<th class="date2">      <strong>OV</strong>         </th>
<th class="date2">      <strong>HV</strong>         </th>
<th>                    <strong>UPDATE</strong>     </th>
<th>                    <strong>DELETE</strong>     </th>




<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<form id="sendtoprint" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="printview.php">
<tr>
<td align="center" >        <input type="checkbox" id="" name="id"    value="printview.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" ></td>
<td align="center">         <?php echo $rows['program'];     ?>                  </td>
<td align="center">         <?php echo $rows['lname']; ?>,         <?php echo $rows['fname']; ?>    </td>
<td align="center">         <?php echo $rows['sex']; ?>         </td>
<td align="center">         <?php echo $rows['phase']; ?>       </td>
<td align="center">         <?php echo $rows['docket']; ?>      </td>
<td align="center">         <?php echo $rows['intake']; ?>      </td>
<td align="center">         <?php echo $rows['address']; ?>     </td>
<td align="center">         <?php echo $rows['phone']; ?>       </td>
<td align="center">         <?php echo $rows['altphone']; ?>    </td>
<td align="center">         <?php echo $rows['lastov']; ?>      </td>
<td align="center">         <?php echo $rows['lasthv']; ?>      </td>
<td align="center">         <?php echo $rows['hv']; ?>          </td>
<td align="center">         <?php echo $rows['ov']; ?>          </td>
<td align="center"><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"><font color="Blue">Update</font></a></td>
<td align="center"><a href="delete_ac.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"><font color="Blue">Delete</font></a></td>
</tr>



<?php
}
?>

</table>
<input style='position:relative; left:-630px; top: -200px;' id="saveForm"  class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Print Selected" />
</form>
</center>
<?php
mysql_close();
?>
```

That is the page that displays the information. Now i need a form with checkboxes that will let them pick what users to send to the other page to print.

Is there a way for this to work or is this more complicated then what I'm trying to do.

if you can help that would be great

Thanks

Adrian

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).